# Regular expression to find 3 repeated words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression which matches the same word 3 times, they are separated by a comma. For example, some inputs would be:

```
HEY,HEY,HEY - match
NO,NO,NO - match
HEY,HI,HEY - no match
HEY,H,Y - no match
HEY,NO,HEY - no match
```

How can I go about doing this? I've had a look at some example but they are only good for characters, not words.

Comment: @varun what's not regular about it? There's 3 words separated by 2 commas

Comment: @Enigmativity I am required to use it, although I am aware there there are other ways to do this. But the requirement is to use regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^(\w+),\1,\1$
```

Explanation:

`^`: beginning of the line. Needed to avoid matching "HHEY,HEY,HEY".

`(\w+)`: matches one or more word characters. This is the first catpured group.

`,`: the character comma.

`\1`: a backreference to the first captured group. In the other words, matches whatever was matched in `(\w+)` before.

`,`: the character comma.

`\1`: a backreference to the first captured group.

`$`: end of the line. Needed to avoid matching "HEY,HEY,HEYY".

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

Example usage

```
static void Main()
{
    var threeWords = new Regex(@"^(\w+),\1,\1$");
    var lines = new[]
    {
        "HEY,HEY,HEY",
        "NO,NO,NO",
        "HEY,HI,HEY",
        "HEY,H,Y",
        "HEY,NO,HEY",
        "HHEY,HEY,HEY",
        "HEY,HEY,HEYY",
    };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var isMatch = threeWords.IsMatch(line) ? "" : "no ";
        Console.WriteLine($"{line} - {isMatch}match");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
HEY,HEY,HEY - match
NO,NO,NO - match
HEY,HI,HEY - no match
HEY,H,Y - no match
HEY,NO,HEY - no match
HHEY,HEY,HEY - no match
HEY,HEY,HEYY - no match
```

Comment: This works! Can you explain what is being done here please?

Comment: `\1` *back reference*, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html for the explanation